# "Negating" a variable in a makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use the `if` function (as opposed to one of the conditional statements) in GNU `make` in order to add a word to a list if a specific variable *isn't* defined. The way I've ended up doing this is to leave the second argument blank while providing the third argument, like so:

```
FOO := baz $(if $(BAR),,quux)
```

This sees to work OK, but strikes me as a little silly. Is there any sort of simple, built-in way to do what I want? I could define my own `not` function, but

```
FOO := baz $(if $(call not,$BAR),quux)
```

isn't much of an improvement in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go this way:

```
ifndef BAR
FOO +=quux
endif
```

or if empty string has meaning "not defined", then:

```
ifeq ($(BAR),)
FOO +=quux
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/make/Conditional-Functions.html):

> The first argument, condition, first
>   has all preceding and trailing
>   whitespace stripped, then is expanded.
>   If it expands to any non-empty string,
>   then the condition is considered to be
>   true. If it expands to an empty
>   string, the condition is considered to
>   be false.

So the question is how would you make a defined variable give an empty string and a non-defined variable give a non-empty string.

You could do this for example using the [`filter` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/make/Text-Functions.html#index-filter-574) combined with the [`origin` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/make/Origin-Function.html#Origin-Function) (`$(if $(filter undefined,$(origin BAR)),quux)`), but that's even uglier than the two examples you provide ^_^